# How to find analytical solution for this linear PDE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Find  $u(x)$ in the interval $x \in(0, l)$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
a \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{~d} x}-\kappa \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 u}{\mathrm{~d} x^2} & =f(x), \quad x \in(0, \ell) \\
u(0) & =0 \\
u(\ell) & =1
\end{aligned}
$$
where $a$ denotes the advective velocity, $\kappa$ is the diffusion coefficient while $f(x)$ is the source.

---

The solution to this for $f \equiv 0$ can be analytically written as
$$
u(x)=\frac{1-\exp (a x / \kappa)}{1-\exp (a \ell / \kappa)}
$$
where $a \ell / \kappa$ is known as the Peclet number $(\mathrm{Pe})$ and measures the ratio of the strength of advection to the strength of diffusion.

---

Can  one explain how analytical solution is coming as $\boxed{
u(x)=\frac{1-\exp (a x / \kappa)}{1-\exp (a \ell / \kappa)}}
$

Comment: Just check. ___

Comment: [$\color{red}{\text{PDE}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation) vs. [$\color{blue}{\text{ODE}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\equiv 0$, the ODE reduces to
$$
au'-\kappa u''=0. \tag{1}
$$
Integrating $(1)$, we obtain
$$
au-\kappa u'=C_1. \tag{2}
$$
Rearranging terms, we can rewrite $(2)$ as
$$
\frac{\kappa u'}{au-C_1}=1. \tag{3}
$$
Integrating both sides of $(3)$ with respect to $x$ we obtain
$$
\frac{\kappa}{a}\ln|au-C_1| = x+C_2 \Rightarrow 
u(x)=C_1'+C_2'e^{ax/\kappa}, \tag{4} 
$$
where $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ are arbitrary constants. To determine them, we use the boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
u(0)=0&\Rightarrow C_1'+ C_2' = 0, \\
u(\ell)=1&\Rightarrow C_1'+ C_2'e^{a\ell/\kappa} = 1. \tag{5}
\end{align}
Solving $(5)$ we obtain
$$
C_1'=-C_2'=-\frac{1}{e^{a\ell/\kappa}-1} \tag{6}
$$
and, finally,
$$
u(x)=\frac{e^{ax/\kappa}-1}{e^{a\ell/\kappa}-1}. \tag{7}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the solution can be written as
\begin{equation}
u(x) = \alpha + \beta e^{\frac{a}{k}x}+ \int_0^\ell \varphi(x-t)f(t)dt
\end{equation}
where $\varphi(x)$ is the fundamental solution
\begin{equation}
\varphi(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}
\\-\frac{1}{a}\quad\text{if}\quad x<0\\
-\frac{1}{a}e^{\frac{a}{k}x}\quad\text{if}\quad x>0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
and $\alpha, \beta$ are suitable constants depending on $f$.

Comment: can you give me a detailed solution?

Comment: This is detailed enough. You can determine $\alpha$  and $\beta$ by writing $u(0)$ and $u(\ell)$.